# What compiler to use for C++

Tags: c++

So I am a Java developer. Wanting to try out C++. But I need a compiler. And oh my god is it complicated. So I want to be able to build for whatever OS I want using Windows 10, and I just can't seem to understand what I need. As with using Java all I do is compile once and I have a working program on whatever OS supports the JVM. Now I know C++ requires a separate build for each OS, but I don't understand what compiler can do that. I think GCC can, but it has been building for over 4 hours now and I don't know if it will ever finish. Please give me a list of compilers that are free that can do what I want it to do. If this is not possible then please explain why because I don't understand anything about C++ compilers. Thanks for investing your time into reading this.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not only about the OS. You can be on MacOS and compile a program with the local toolchain, yet it will not run on all MacOS devices. Why? A lot have `x64` architecture, but the newer devices moved to use `arm64` processors, so not only do you have to worry about OS, but architecture as well. Linux is even more over the place in this light as you can basically install the linux kernel onto anything that has a C compiler, so `x64`, `RISCV` anything goes. Java bypasses this as it doesn't run on "bare-metal", but C++ doesn't have that luxury.

Comment: One thing you can do is use something like [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to make it easier to compile your program on different platforms.

Comment: I found WSL2 to be a very easy way how do Linux work on W10.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, compiling natively (using the same OS you want to run the results on) is going to be a lot easier. You can use a VM for it.

But cross-compilation (using one OS to compile for the other) is possible.

---

There are 3 major compilers: GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

MSVC only works on Windows and builds for Windows. The other two are cross-platform.

GCC is old and time-tried. Clang is new and shiny, and tries to do things "the right way"™.

In particular, cross-compilation (e.g. Windows to Linux) is a lot easier with Clang. Most probably all you need to do is to install the regular Windows Clang, and have a directory with a Linux installation in it (that itself has GCC or Clang installed), and specify the path to it using `--sysroot=...` when invoking Clang (the Windows one). You will also need `--target=...` to specify the target platform (and the easiest way to determine it is running `clang --version` on said platform; use a VM if needed). Use the oldest Linux you want to support, since the resulting binaries won't be backward-compatible.

The same thing should *in theory* work with every OS Clang supports.

Cross-compilation with GCC is going to be a lot harder, since you'll need to either compile or find a version built specifically to cross-compile from Windows to Linux, which won't be easy, since it's a rare use-case.

So Clang is your best bet here, and I see it as the best choice even ignoring cross-compilation.

---

If this doesn't work for you, you'll have to use virtual machines: a Linux VM to build your apps for Linux, and so on.

Comment: mingw (based on gcc) can do cross-compilation from Linux to Windows.

Comment: @Ripi2 I know, but OP wants it the other way, Windows to Linux. Had a typo in the answer, fixed now.

Comment: These days, WSL is probably the easiest way to compile for linux from windows. I would not call that "cross compiling" tho..

Answer (score 0):

Every OS uses a different scheme for the executable file. Even 32/64 bit versions are different. That means that you need a different compilation for each different "target".

The easiest option is to have several OSs and do your complations in each OS, with the compiler you wish (gcc, clang, Microsoft's, etc).  Using the tool CMAKE will save you some headeaches when settting the configuration for each target, as many of them are common to CMAKE usage..

You can also do cross-compiling, which means that you compile in one enviroment (eg. Linux) but the final executable will be run [only] in other target (eg. Windows). This procedure is more complicated, but once you control it you can save time and work in the OS you feel more comfortably.

Another thing to take into account is that GUI controls are handled by the OS. So, yo need different coding for different OS. In Java this is done automatically by its own components. For C++ you may use special libs such as wxWidgets or Qt.

Answer (score -2):

GCC shouldn't build 4 hours on normal hardware worth to start your C++ learning adventure. Unless you did not use "make -j" from your command shell to utilize. Welcome to the hell of C++ build tools and build universe.

It is the best to use only standardized C++ and the "native" compiler on your platform. For windows this means downloading Visual Studio Community Edition.

You will soon either give up or learn enough about how to do it right from the command line.

Comment: Good advice, but ... I understood from the question that there is the wish for cross-compiling to every OS "someone wants"  like ... send in all languages on all frequencies ... I doubt this question can be answered without changing reality.